# The integration of radially symmetric function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $u\in C^\infty(\overline{B(0,1)})$ is radially symmetric. i.e., there exists a function $v$: $\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R$ such that $u(x)=v(|x|)$. Here we take $B(0,1)\subset \mathbb R^2$.

Notice that $|\nabla u(x)|=|v'(x)|$. And we use $x=(x_1,x_2)$ where $x_1=r\cos\theta$ for $r=|x|$.

My question is: How we prove that 
$$ \int_{B(0,1)} \frac{{v'(r)\frac{x_1}{|{x}|}}}{|{v'(r)}|+\sqrt{(v'(r))^2+c_1^2+c_2^2+2[{v'(r)\frac{x_1}{|{x}|}c_1+v'(r)\frac{x_2}{|{x}|}c_2}]}}dx =0 \tag 1$$

Here $c_1$ and $c_2$ are two arbitrary constants.

Also, the denominate comes from 
$$|{v'(r)}|+\sqrt{(v'(r))^2+c_1^2+c_2^2+2[{v'(r)\frac{x_1}{|{x}|}c_1+v'(r)\frac{x_2}{|{x}|}c_2}]} =\int_{B(0,1)} \sqrt{(\partial_1u+c_1)^2+(\partial_2u+c_2)^2}\,dx $$

Notice that it is very quick to prove that 
$$ \int_{B(0,1)} {v'(r)\frac{x_1}{|{x}|}}=0 $$
by doing integration with respect to $x_1$ first. But I still have trouble on how to prove $(1)$...

Any help is really welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is true. Take $v'(r)\equiv 1$, $c_1=1$, $c_2=0$.  In polar coordinates, the integral $(1)$ becomes 
$$\int_0^1 r\,dr \int_0^{2\pi} 
\frac{\cos \theta}{1+\sqrt{2+2\cos\theta}}  d\theta $$
The inner integral evaluates to $\approx -0.6623$, so the whole thing is negative.

Comment: You are right...now I need to find out another way... Thank you!